# How to create a dictionary with multiple columns

Tags: windows-phone-8, dictionary, collections

I am working on a Windows Phone 8 app and I have some data that I need to work with.  I am reading the data from a website and I have basically 4 pieces of information coming in from the website.  I need to be able to do some parsing and filtering on this data before displaying it so I would like to add it to some sort of array/collection/dictionary.

Before with a C# WinForms app, I would just create a DataTable in memory that had 4 columns and just add a row for each entry.  I don't think I can use DataTables with Windows Phone so I am wondering what other ways I can store this information in memory.  The app doesn't store any information so I have no real need to use IsolatedStorage for any of this.

Is there some sort of Dictionary/Collection that I can use that will do something similar to a DataTable?  In that it will let me store 4 pieces of information per entry?

Thanks!

Comment: Just create a class that has the four properties you need and add them to a `List<YourType>` or a `Dictionary<YourType>`

Comment: This sounds interesting and possibly the way to go, how do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need something simple, you could create a class which will hold the data:

```
public class DataFromWebSite
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string Telephone { get; set; }
}
```

In the example above, I've used a strongly-typed class where each property could hold an exact value/data-type. So, `Age` is an `integer` rather than being a `string` for example.

Then, I'd create a collection object to hold the values:

```
var list = new ObservableCollection<DataFromWebSite>();

// add items to the list...
list.Add(new DataFromWebSite
{
    Name = "John",
    Age = 42,
    Country = "Antartica",
    Telephone = "941223445"
});
list.Add(new DataFromWebSite
{
    Name = "Carrol",
    Age = 24,
    Country = "Atlantis",
    Telephone = "100223445"
});
```

`ObservableCollection`s work well with UIs where the list may change over time. For example, a ListBox bound to an `ObservableCollection` will show changes to the list when items are added or removed (but it won't show changes to the properties such as `Age` without implementing `INotifyPropertyChange`).

Then, using some of the LINQ extensions, you can do simple/readable queries:

```
var greaterThan30 = list.Where(d => d.Age > 30);
foreach (var item in greaterThan30)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("{0}-{1}", item.Name, item.Age);
}
```

The above would produce a list that has only objects where the `Age` property is greater than `30`.

Or you could use LINQ:

```
var greaterThan30 = from d in list
                     where d.Age > 30
                     select d;
```

If one of the values being returned was unique (for example an `ID`):

```
public class DataFromWebSite
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Telephone { get; set; }
}
```

You could store the list as a `Dictionary<string, DataFromWebSite>`:

```
var keyed = new Dictionary<string, DataFromWebSite>();
var d = new DataFromWebSite
{
    Id = "ABC123-A";
    Name = "John",
    Age = 42,
    Telephone = "941223445"
};

keyed.Add(d.Id, d);
// to get a value back:
if (keyed.ContainsKey("ABC123-A")) {
    var d2 = keyed["ABC123-A"];
}
```

And, if you wanted to get the list from the Dictionary:

```
var list = keyed.Values.ToArray();
```

Comment: This looks good.  One more question, I think storing the list as a dictionary is the way to go.  But how do I query and pull out a specific entry?  Using the ID as the key in your example, how do I query by an ID and pull out all the information for that entry such as Name, age, Telephone?

Comment: Added a simple example using the indexer. The documentation for Dictionary explains all of the options.

Comment: Thanks, got it sorted.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of an open-ended questions for XAML (as you're really asking how use collection controls and how to do binding).

Basically, any collection would do, then use a control to bind to the various properties of elements in that collection.  You could use a `ListBox` control, bind it to the collection, then declare an `ItemTemplate` within it to bind to the various properties within the elements in the collection.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Customers}" Margin="0,5,0,10">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                <TextBlock Padding="3,0,3,0"
      Text="{Binding FirstName}" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeSmall}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding LastName}" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeSmall}"/>
                <TextBlock Text=", " FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeSmall}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Address}" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeSmall}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

And you'd set the `DataContext` of the page (or name the `ListBox` and set *its* `DataContext`) to an object that has property named `Customers` which is the collection you want to view in a list box e.g.:

```
public MyPage()
{
    //...
    DataContext = this;
}
public List<Customer> Customers {get;set;}
```

I've ignored `INotifyPropertyChanged`, I'll leave that as an exercise to the reader.